# How to put an array in message?

Tags: python, arrays, django, message

Just a simple question, how can i insert the content of an array to my message?

```
messages.info(request, "text_a" , array , "text_b")
```

This only provides me "text_a" after displaying a message.

Comment: Make a formatted string, the `messages.info` function doesn't take unlimited arguments

Answer (score 0):

You can use messages.info(request, "text_a" , '  '.join(array), "text_b")

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish. Can you add some more context to your post? What is `messages`?